# using pip3 with sudo in aws command line

Tags: sudo

I have installed pip3 using these commands

```
sudo yum install -y python35-setuptools
sudo easy_install-3.5 pip
```

I tried installing a package through

```
pip3 install <package_name>
```

I got permission denied error.

Then I tried

```
sudo pip3 install <pakcage_name>
```

I got -> sudo: pip3: command not found

kindly help me to get through this.
Thanks in advance.